# Transforming without setting RenderTransform

Tags: c#, wpf, transform, rendertransform

I'm trying to simply transform a `Control` but I don't want to use the `UIElement.RenderTransform` Property as it is possible that this has been set from outside of the `Control`.
Is there another way to do such `Transformations` on Controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [TransformGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup.aspx) to combine your transform with the already set transform.

```
var currentTransform = this.RenderTransform;
var myTransform = new RotateTransForm()
{
    Angle = 90
};
var group = new TransformGroup();
group.Children.Add(currentTransform);
group.Children.Add(myTransform);

this.RenderTransform = group;
```